# How to add a trailing slash to this one particular url in apache

Tags: apache

When a user types in www.example.co.uk/beta, I want the traffic to be sent to www.example.co.uk/beta/. But only for that url ie, when the url ends /beta.

How do I accomplish this in apache?

I have tried:

```
<Location /beta>
    DirectorySlash Off
    ProxyPass  http://testserver.co.uk
    ProxyPassReverse http://testserver.co.uk
</Location>
```

With no success

Please note the proxypass directives are for my reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier using .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  beta$  /beta/  [NC]
```

I offer no promises that this won't loop, but it's worth a try. Add a [R=301] flag if you want to inform the visitor/search engine that they should use the trailing-slash version. Add a ? after /beta/ if you want to suppress any Query String that comes with it.